# AttributeError: 'AnimalShelter' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter, attributeerror

I am getting this weird error "AttributeError: 'AnimalShelter' object has no attribute 'read'". It looks like the file is completely ignoring that I defined read in the Mod4.py file. I've attached both files. Please let me know if you notice something I don't. I am using Jupyter and Jupyter Notebook.

My error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-a045b9e49a08> in <module>
     27 
     28 # call the read method
---> 29 results = assignment.read({"type":"dog"})
     30 print(results)

AttributeError: 'AnimalShelter' object has no attribute 'read'
```

My Mod4Test.ipynb

```
from Mod4 import AnimalShelter

assignment = AnimalShelter()
animal_data = [
{"name":"Ruby",
"type":"dog"},
{"name":"Max",
"type":"dog"},
{"name":"Penguin",
"type":"cat"}
]

#for i in animal_data:
#    a.create(i)

#data = a.read({"type":"dog"})
#for dog in data:
#    print(dog)

criteria = {"type":"dog"}

# instantiate an object of AnimalShelter class

# call the create method
success = assignment.create(animal_data)
print(success)

# call the read method
results = assignment.read({"type":"dog"})
print(results)
```

and here is my Mod4.py file

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections.

        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:28369')
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

        # Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            insert = self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary \n",
            if insert!=0:
                return True
            else:
                return False           
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
        # Create method to implement the R in CRUD.
    def read(self, criteria=None):
        # criteria is not None then this find will return all rows which matches the criteria
        if criteria:
        # {'_id':False} just omits the unique ID of each row
            data = self.database.animals.find(criteria,{"_id":False})
        else:
        #if there is no search criteria then all the rows will be return
            data = self.database.animals.find({} , {"_id":False})
        return data
```

Comment: In your code, do you have spaces between your methods?

Comment: @Woody1193 No, at least none that I have noticed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with your code. How about this: open your Python interpreter and try the following code:

`from Mod4 import AnimalShelter; import inspect; inspect.getmembers(AnimalShelter, predicate=inspect.ismethod)`

If that doesn't print out the `read` function then it probably means that you have some sort of formatting issue. Otherwise, it's something with Jupyter.

Comment: @Woody1193  I submitted my homework and got a 100 so I'm not too worried about it anymore lol. And yeah I figure something is up with Jupyter because when I tried to add the code you provided it still gave me the same error.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Okay. In that case, I'm going to vote to close this question because I think it's probably the result of a typo or can't be reproduced. This doesn't mean you've done anything wrong; your question simply has limited utility to the SO community. Please feel free to post additional questions in the future.